# How to release a locked file on Azure Web Apps? (formerly: jspm install issues)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, aurelia, jspm, kudu

Until the latest version of aurelia beta, I was happily deploying to Azure running `jspm update` as part of the deployment command.
However, since the latest beta, `update` fails with

`err  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\local\LocalAppData\.jspm\packages\npm\aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.0.2\dist\amd' -> 'D:\local\LocalAppData\.jspm\packages\npm\.tmp-aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.0.2'
         at Error (native)`

In an attempt to resolve this myself I have used the following at the Kudu command prompt:

`jspm clean`

`jspm install aurelia-templating`

`jspm update aurelia-templating`

Needless to say running `jspm update` on my local machine works fine, which strongly suggests that this is a permissions problem in Azure in D:\Local\LocalAppData.

Is there some way to change the permissions in this folder, or is this a problem with the aurelia-templating package itself?

Comment: You said you had been running this before and it has stopped working?

Comment: Yes it was working fine prior to the release of aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.0.2

Comment: You should have rename privileges in D:/local so this doesn't seem like a sandbox issue. You can get that error if something else has a lock on the file. Have you tried this on a fresh Web App instance?

Comment: I managed to track it down to one file, namely `jspm_packages/github/systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.20.js`. When trying to delete this file I am getting an `access is denied error`.
How would I be able to release the lock on this file? I'm fairly sure that this is a problem just in this instance of my web app.
Is there some way of "rebooting" the IIS instance? I'm getting to the point that I will recreate the web app and delete this one.

Comment: I managed to fix it in the end. I restarted the app from the button on the portal page (I'd never noticed it before!), then manually deleted each subfolder of jspm_packages, then ran jspm clean and jspm update.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Nice. I had a similar issue yesterday with meteor not unlocking things and I had to restart as well, glad you figured that out! :)

Comment: Proposed a title change and posted the answer so others who might have this issue can easily see the fix. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix file locking issues, just restart your Web App from the portal. This will cause a cold-restart to happen. If you're running a production site, be aware of this downtime.

[image]